# How to implement the Music Metadata Or Music MetaData Browser npm plugin in Cypress V10?

Tags: npm, cypress, node-modules, cypress-component-test-runner, cypress-configuration

I tried to implement the Node plugin in Cypress Version 10, But I couldn't done it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/music-metadata-browser#fetchurl-function

1. Installation is done:
   `npm install --save-dev music-metadata-browser`
   `npm install --save-dev util`
2. Added the  below lines in plugin/index.js

> ```
> const musicMetadata = require('music-metadata-browser');
> const util = require('util');
>
> module.exports = (on, config) => {
>   require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
>   on('task', {
>     validateAudioFormat(audioTrackUrl) {
>       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
>         musicMetadata.parseFile(audioTrackUrl, (err, data) => {
>           if (err) {
>             return reject(err);
>           }
>           return resolve(data);
>         });
>       });
>     },
>
>   });
> };
> ```

3. Added the below code in e2e/validateFile.cy.js

> ```
> describe('Parsing File', () => {
>   it('Validating Audio File', () => {
>     const audioURL = 'cypress/fixtures/media/Patrikios.mp3';
>     console.log('url: ' +  audioURL);
>     cy.task('validateAudioFormat', audioURL).then(data => {
>         const allData = Object.values(data);
>         console.log('All data: ' + allData);
>     });
>
> /******
>     cy.on('validateAudioFormat', (url) => {
>       async () => {
>         const metadata = await mm.fetchFromUrl(url);
>         console.log('url: ' + url);
>         console.log(util.inspect(metadata, { showHidden: false, depth: null }));
>       };
>     });
> *****/
>   });
> });
> ```

**Error:**

> ```
> CypressError: `cy.task('validateAudioFormat')` failed with the following error: 
>
> The task 'validateAudioFormat' was not handled in the setupNodeEvents method. The following tasks are registered: resetCoverage, combineCoverage, coverageReport
>
> Fix this in your setupNodeEvents method here: /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/cypress.config.js
> ```

**Commented block error:**

> ```
> taskreadAudioFiles, cypress/fixtures/media/audios/valid/Beyond_Patrick_Patrikios.mp3
> CypressError
> cy.task('readAudioFiles') timed out after waiting 60000ms
> ```

Anyone can help on this scenario?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your project is a mixture of Cypress v9 config and Cypress v10 tests.

I presume you are on 10+ so the plugins now go in `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')
const musicMetadata = require('music-metadata-browser');
const util = require('util');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);

      on('task', {
        validateAudioFormat(audioTrackUrl) {
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            musicMetadata.parseFile(audioTrackUrl, (err, data) => {
              if (err) {
                return reject(err);
              }
              return resolve(data);
            });
          });
        },
      });

    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes @Fody. I include the below on the cypress.config.js file. Your code is also tried.
`return require('./cypress/plugins/index.js')(on, config)`

Still I am getting an Error:  `musicMetadata.parseFile is not a function`

Comment: Well at least the error message has changed! I will see if it works here. By the way, I don't see any actual testing going on - just logging. What would you expect from the data?

Comment: Yes. you are right! I have to parse the mp3/mp4 file which has valid or not. `Ex: user can use info.txt file has renamed as info.mp3 and tried to upload.` In this case, I have to validate. Now, I am getting an error when I called the `musicMetadata.parseFile` function. How should I include the file, I tried with import that is also showing error "Import" is not acceped. Is there anyother way for the fix.

Comment: I've just been trying it - so far it's crash and burn. There is definitely no `.parseFile()` but it looks like `.parseBlob()` should work (according to examples) - except another error comes up. Will try again shortly.

Comment: Thank you for the support! But I am getting an error "musicMetadata" is not a function when I called the `.parseFile()` or `.parseBlob()`

Comment: I'm getting `File is undefined` with `.parseBlob()`, and looking at the package it is trying to handle the file path. Can't quite figure out the issues with that yet.